# Can't Log on to Windows 10 PC because Microsoft Account was Deleted

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, login, login-screen

I'd really appreciate some help on this. I recently set up a Microsoft account for my niece and used it to log in to a new computer intended to be given to her. I downloaded any programmes she'd need like Office and such, then logged out and shut down the computer. I went to log in to the account online, but because she's a minor, it asked me to enter a parent's email address to get permission from. I entered my sister's email (her mother), but she never verfied the account access.

Today, she recieved a text message saying the email address was closed which was a surprise. Now we can't log into the computer because it says the account doesn't exist. When I try to use the "recover account" feature, it says the account doesn't exist, and when I try to set up a new account with the same email, I'm told the address is already taken. I was under the impression that an account could be reopened by trying to log in within 30 days of closure, but that doesn't seem to be correct in this case as I recieve the message "This account does not exist" whenever I try to.

My sister logged in to her email address, but she's had nothing else from Microsoft other than the initial verification email which now says "This link has expired. Please log on to your child's account to send another verification." if she tries to use it now.

I've tried enabling the hidden admin account by going into Command Prompt from the troubleshoot screen that appears after pressing shift + restart, but even though the command says it's a success, the admin account never appears in the log on screen. Even if the network is turned off, she still can't log on locally. We have absolutely no means of getting into the computer now. Even if I try to boot into safe mode, and enter the correct password, it boots us back out to the log in screen.

My sister and niece desperately need that computer because home schooling is done from there. I'd really like to avoid reinstalling Windows if possible because I'm now in a different country to them and my sister is not very confident with technology, especially computers. Also, because she'd have to set up and download everything again.

I've looked around lots of forums, the Microsoft website, and tried to find a way to contact Microsoft (because the virtual agent has been useless to me), but have found absolutely nothing that helps.

The computer is a Lenovo laptop running Windows 10 intended for personal use (i.e. not connnected to a domain).

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

P.S. Just something I noticed when in Command Prompt which may be relevent, the console kept returning a message that "shutdown" was not an internal or external command, or a batch or executable file, so the regular commands for shutting down and restarting wouldn't work (first time I've come across that).